# Add Remove program Icon

Tags: wix

I have a WIX Installer project, which installs my product.
The code was not written by me. 
It shows an Icon in the Add/Remove programs. I want to know where is in the source code is it specified. That icon is of the main executable of my product.
I tried searching the code but could not find any ARPPRODUCTICON word in the whole code.
From where is the icon getting displayed in Add/Remove Programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The icon is set automatically by Windows Installer. If you want to use a custom one, you can set ARPPRODUCTICON property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367593(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, Windows Installer does its best to guess the icon for Add/Remove programs. It does its job quite well. Yet if your product contains several applications, to which you create shortcuts in Start menu, it can get the wrong icon. So if you want to make sure the right icon is displayed, set [`ARPPRODUCTICON`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367593.aspx) property; this way it can different from your main executable icon.